# Using SUM in CASE if value is numeric

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a similar situation to the `CASE` clause well known problem:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1;
SELECT CASE WHEN @i = 1 THEN 1 ELSE MIN(1/0) END;
```

In that case the code will throw an exception, `Divide by zero error encountered`, even though in theory you would never reach that `min(1/0)` scenario.

So I have similar situation:

```
CASE WHEN CodeValue in ('Numeric1','Numeric2') THEN SUM(cast(VarcharValue as int)) ELSE max(VarcharValue) END
```

In other words I need to use `SUM` function if `VarcharValue` is numeric (it could be determined by `CodeValue` if it is numeric), if that's not the case, I need return `VarcharValue` with `MAX` function.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a strange construct, because one `case` branch returns a string and another a number.  SQL Server decides, in such a case, that the expression returns a number.

And you'll have problems with the `ELSE`, because a non-numeric string will be converted to a number.  Error.

The following *might* work:

```
(CASE WHEN CodeValue in ('Numeric1', 'Numeric2') 
      THEN CAST(VARCHAR(MAX), SUM(CAST(VarcharValue as int)))
      ELSE MAX(VarcharValue)
 END)
```

You might still have a problem, if the `SUM()` is being calculated over all data before filtering (which I think is possible with an aggregation query).  My recommendation is to upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server and use:

```
(CASE WHEN CodeValue in ('Numeric1', 'Numeric2') 
      THEN CAST(VARCHAR(MAX), SUM(TRY_CAST(VarcharValue as int)))
      ELSE MAX(VarcharValue)
 END)
```

However, you can repeat the `CASE` logic:

```
(CASE WHEN CodeValue in ('Numeric1', 'Numeric2') 
      THEN CAST(VARCHAR(MAX), SUM(CASE WHEN CodeValue in ('Numeric1', 'Numeric2')  THEN CAST(VarcharValue as int) END))
      ELSE MAX(VarcharValue)
 END)
```

Comment: First one is returning: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int", second doesn't work as I'm using sql 2008, but the last one works, thank you :)